# wpa_supplicant usage in a C program

Tags: c, linux, wireless

I use `wpa_supplicant` via `posix_spawnp()` or `system()` in a C code

is it possible to use the `wpa_supplicant` as a regular POSIX function by including some headers on the code?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the wpa_supplicant control interface, see [wpa_supplicant control interface](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html) documentation.

Comment: the document explains what the wpa_ctrl.c and .h  are but I could not understand how I need to use them, e.g. what sequence I would need them and seeing an example would be good to understand its usage. Do you suggest another webpage, blog, document to understand how I need to use the control interface?

Comment: This is old question, but wpa_cli is the answer :)